# Replace a center pixel value in a NumPy array with a maximum value in the same array

Tags: python, numpy

Suppose a variable contains multiple arrays like:

```
data = array([[1,2,3],
             [4,5,6],
             [10,11,12]],dtype=float32)

       array([[1,2,3],
               [4,5,6],
               [7,8,9]],dtype=float32)
```

I want to compare the center element (ie. `5` in both the arrays) with all of the elements in their respective arrays and return the largest element whose value is greater than 2 times of the center element (5x2=10 in both of the arrays) otherwise return the center element.

The expected output for the above example:

```
 data = [[12],
        [5]]
```

Comment: What is the middle element for a 4x4 array for example?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Usually, I will deal with only either 3x3 or 5x5 or 7x7. So that problem won't arise. Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean those to be lists or arrays or lists in your examples? Do you really mean to return the max element of the array as long as it is at least 2xcentre? If not, how do you resolve it if there are multiple values > 10?

Comment: @DavidBuck Yes. I want to return the max element of the array as long as it is at least 2xcentre. I updated the question for further clarity. Kindly check.

Comment: I noticed that you had used a 3D array in your example above. Not sure if that's a typo, but I assumed it would be a 2d array in the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do what I think you're asking for:

```
import numpy as np

data = [np.array([[1, 2, 3],
                   [4, 5, 6],
                   [9, 11, 12]], dtype=int),
        np.array([[1, 2, 3],
                   [4, 5, 6],
                   [7, 8, 9]], dtype=int)]

output = []
for arr in data:
    centre = arr[len(arr)//2, len(arr)//2]
    maximum = np.max(arr)
    if maximum > (centre * 2):
        output.append(maximum)
    else:
        output.append(centre)

print(output)
```

Output

```
[12, 5]
```

As an interesting aside, from Python 3.8 you can use the assignment (aka Walrus) operator to do this in a single list line.

```
print([maximum if (maximum:= np.max(x)) > ((centre := x[(point := len(x)//2), point]) * 2) else centre for x in data])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np 

def getMax(array): 
    shape = array.shape
    l = shape[0]
    r = shape[1]
    middle = array[l // 2, r // 2]
    _max = np.amax(array)
    return _max if _max > 2 * middle else middle

d1 = np.array([[1,2,3],
               [4,5,6],
               [9,10,11]])

d2 = np.array([[1,2,3],
               [4,5,6],
               [7,8,9]])

data = [d1, d2]

ans = []
for d in data:
    ans.append(getMax(d))

print(ans) # [11, 5]
```

This is what i got for 3 by 3 matrix, assuming you're using numpy.